# Как модифицировать скрипт дабы он запоминал значения и писал их в localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Предыстория: начал использовать в проекте SVg. На каждой странице их достаточно много но многие из них повторяются по несколько раз. Писать svg код в html не мог, было запрещено. И было два варианта либо task для сборки( использую gulp ) либо другой выход. Остановился на импорт как обычные изображение но дабы браузер разворачивал svg код нашел скрипт. И выглядит это как то так

```
<img src='path/to/svg' class='svg>
```

А есть скрипт который помогает браузеру разварачивать svg код( т.е в браузере полный svg код) ( это надо было для работы с CSS)

Сам код :

```
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                        $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                        $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

});
```

Однако как я упоминал ранее svg много и они повторяются. Но скрипт загружает каждую по новую не сохраняя ее в localstorage. К примеру если я задал в 4 местах 
 то могу заметить во вкладке network что он загрузит ее 4 раза, и за чего на одной странице идет подгрузка по 20-30 файлов вместо 5-6. Возможно ли модифицировать скрипт дабы не было такой ситуации и браузер загружал один файл - один раз. Спасибо заранее буду очень признателен за помощь